# how to make the relationship between Customer,Products,categories,and order. And how to implement the form tags for this

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-boot, backend

I have Product,Customer,order entities. I need to find the relationship to get all of these entities gathered on the Order entity which it will hold the customer information and the product information.

in this Html page, I need to create to link this information that will be added to the order entity so when i create another page to get all the orders so i can view all the orders with the information been inserted by the user.

[image: Make A bill HTML page]

Category Entity class

```
@Entity
@Data
public class Categories {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long categories_id;

    private String categoryName;
```

Customer Entity class

```
@Entity
@Data
@Table(name="customers")
public class Customers {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long customer_id;
    private String customer_fName;
    private String customer_lName;
    private String customer_email;
    private String customer_address;
    private String customer_state;
    private String customer_phone;
    private String customer_zipCode;

    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Orders.class,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "customer_order_fk",referencedColumnName = "customer_id")//means will be a fk in orders table
    private List<Orders> orders;

    public Customers()
    {
        super();
    }

    public Customers(String customer_fName, String customer_lName, String customer_email, String customer_phone,String customer_address ,String customer_state,String customer_zipCode) {
        this.customer_zipCode = customer_zipCode;
        this.customer_phone = customer_phone;
        this.customer_state = customer_state;
        this.customer_address = customer_address;
        this.customer_fName = customer_fName;
        this.customer_lName = customer_lName;
        this.customer_email = customer_email;
    }
```

Product Entity class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "Products")
@Data
public class Products {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private long product_id;

    private String product_name;

    private BigDecimal product_price;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "categories_id",nullable = false) //the name of the column in the other class and that name will be a column in the class
    private Categories product_category;

    private String product_quantity;

    private String product_Section;

    private String product_ExpDate;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name = "")
    private Customers customer;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = "order_order_id")
    private Orders order;

    public Products()
    {
        super();
    }

    public Products(String product_name, BigDecimal product_price,String product_quantity, String product_Section,String product_ExpDate) {
        this.product_name = product_name;
        this.product_price = product_price;
        this.product_quantity = product_quantity;
        this.product_Section = product_Section;
        this.product_ExpDate = product_ExpDate;
    }
```

Order Controller class

```
@Controller
```

public class OrdersController {

```
@Autowired
private OrdersService ordersService;

@Autowired
private CustomerService customerService;

@Autowired
private ShoppingCartImpService shoppingCartImpService;

@ModelAttribute("order")
public Orders orders()
{
    return new Orders();
}

@GetMapping("/orders/getAllorders")
public String listAllOrders(Model model)
{
    model.addAttribute("order",ordersService.getAllOrders());
    return "showTransactions";
}

@GetMapping("/orders/delete/{id}")
public String deleteOrderById(@PathVariable Long id)
{
    ordersService.deleteOrder(id);
    return "redirect:/orders/getAllorders";
}

@PostMapping("/orders/save/order")
public String saveOrders(@ModelAttribute("order") Orders orders)
{
    ordersService.saveOrders(orders);

    return "redirect:/orders/getAllorders";
}

@GetMapping("/showTransaction/customer/{id}") //this to list all items choosen by a specific customer
public String showShoppingCart(Model model,@PathVariable Long id)
{
    Customers customer = customerService.getCustomerById(id);

    List<CartItem> listCartItems = shoppingCartImpService.listCartItems(customer);//customer.id

    model.addAttribute("CartItems",listCartItems);

    return "showTransactions";
}
```

Make A bill HTML page

```
<h4 class="mb-3">Customer Information</h4>
            <form class="needs-validation" novalidate="" th:action="@{/orders/save/order}" method="post" th:object="${order}" id="form">
                <div class="row g-3">
                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <label for="firstName" class="form-label">First name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="firstName"  placeholder="" value="" required="" autofocus th:field="*{customer_fname}">
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            Valid first name is required.
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="col-sm-6">
                        <label for="lastName" class="form-label">Last name</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="lastName" placeholder="" value="" required="" autofocus th:field="*{customer_lname}">
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            Valid last name is required.
                        </div>
                    </div>


                    <div class="col-12">
                        <br>
                        <label for="address" class="form-label">Address</label>
                        <input type="text" class="form-control" id="address" placeholder="Address" required="" autofocus th:field="*{customer_address}">
                        <div class="invalid-feedback">
                            Please enter your shipping address.
                        </div>
                    </div>

                </div>

                <br>
                <hr class="my-4">

                <!--product info-->

                <div class="row g-3">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <h4 class="mb-3">Select A Product</h4>
                        <br>

                        <label th:for="category"> Category : </label>
                        <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="category" name="category" autofocus>
                            <option value="">Select Category</option>
                            <option th:each = "product: ${product}"
                                    th:text="${product.product_category}"
                            >
                            </option>
                        </select>

                        <br>
                        <label th:for="product"> Product Name : </label>
                        <select class="form-control form-control-sm" id="product" name="product" autofocus>
                            <option value="">Select Product</option>
                            <option th:each = "product: ${product}"
                                    th:text="${product.product_name}"
                            >
                            </option>
                        </select>

                        <br>
                        <label th:for="product_price"> Product Price : </label>
                        <input class="form-control form-control-sm" id="product_price" name="product_price" disabled >

                        <br>
                        <label th:for="roles"> Product Quantity : </label>
                        <input class="form-control form-control-sm" id="product_Qty" name="product_Qty" autofocus>

                        <br>

                        <button class="w-5 btn btn-primary " type="submit" id="add_submit" >Add </button>

                    </div>
                </div>
                <br>
                <hr class="my-4">

                <!-- TABLE -->

                <table class = "table table-striped table-bordered" id="show">
                    <thead class = "table-white">
                    <tr>
                        <th> Category </th>
                        <th> Product Name </th>
                        <th> Product Price </th>
                        <th> Product Quantity </th>
                        <th> Total </th>
                        <th> Edit </th>
                        <th> Delete </th>
                    </tr>
                    </thead>

                    <tbody>

                    <tr th:each = "product: ${product}"> <!-- this attribute to list up products  -->

                        <td th:text="${product.product_category}" ></td>
                        <td th:text="${product.product_name}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${product.product_price}"></td>
                        <td th:text="${product.product_quantity}" ></td>
                        <td th:text="${product.product_quantity}" ></td>

                        <td> <center> <a th:href="@{/products/edit/{id}(id=${product.product_id})}" style="color: green"> Edit </a> </center> </td>

                        <td> <center> <a th:href="@{/products/delete_product/{id}(id=${product.product_id}) }" style="color: red"> Delete </a> </center> </td>

                    </tr>

                    </tbody>

                </table>




                <h4 class="mb-3"></h4>

                <br>

                <div class="row g-3">
                    <div class="col-12">
                        <h5 class="mb-3" id="total_bill"> Total: $</h5>
                    </div>
                </div>

                <br>

                <button class="w-100 btn btn-primary btn-lg" type="submit">Generate Bill</button>
            </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can manage mapping between Customers and Order in a separate database table you can map orders in Customers Entity as:

```
    @OneToMany(targetEntity = Orders.class,cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinTable(name = "customers_orders", 
               joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "customer_id"),
               inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "order_id"))
    private List<Orders> orders;
```

you have to manage CascadeType that if you want to persist or want to only fetch orders related to customers.